# How to scale ghost image when drag image over a div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Please help me make effect scale x2 ghost image when user drag that image over a div like this follow video:

[image]

Here is my code (I tried use e.dataTransfer.setDragImage to update image in event "dragenter" but it's not working ):

```js
var containerElement = document.getElementById('containter');
containerElement.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
 // Need scale image here
 var ghostImageElement = document.getElementById('drag_ghost_image');
 $(ghostImageElement).width($(dragImage).width() * 2);
 $(ghostImageElement).height($(dragImage).height() * 2);

 e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ghostImageElement, 0, 0);

}, true);

containerElement.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
 // Need scale image here
 var ghostImageElement = document.getElementById('drag_ghost_image');
 $(ghostImageElement).width($(dragImage).width());
 $(ghostImageElement).height($(dragImage).height());

 e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ghostImageElement, 0, 0);

}, true);

var dragImageElement = document.getElementById('dragImage');
dragImageElement.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {

 // Make trace image
 var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
 crt.setAttribute('id', 'drag_ghost_image');
 crt.style.position = "absolute";
 crt.style.top = "0";
 crt.style.right = "0";
 $(crt).width($(this).width());
 $(crt).height($(this).height());

 document.body.appendChild(crt);
 e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);


}, true);

dragImageElement.addEventListener('dragend', function(e) {
 var element = document.getElementById('drag_ghost_image');
 element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div>
  <img id="dragImage"
    src="https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/demo-thumb.jpg" 
    data-large-img="https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/demo-big.jpg">
 </div>
 <div id="containter" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: gray">
  Drag over me
 </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: did you get any solution?